# Issue with the rectangle position

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

My concept is simple, I've got draw one square for each character I have in a textarea element. The enviroment to draw them is a 500x500 canvas. But the problem is: I'm not being able to jump to the next line when the squares hit the limit of 500px.

Each square is 10x10, therefore, just 50 squares can fit in a single row with 500px.

Here's my code:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<button id="convert">Draw Squares</button><br>

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        text = document.getElementById("text");

    var y = 0;

    document.getElementById("convert").addEventListener("click", function(){
        context.beginPath();

        for(var i = 0; i < text.value.length; i++){
            if(i > 0 && i % 50 == 0) y++; // Here I try to jump to the next line
            context.rect(i * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
        }

        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fill();
    });
</script>
```

The problem might be inside the loop, however, I have no idea what's the actual issue there.

Comment: Your `y` value is correct, but you have to move `x` back to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y` value is correct, but you need to reset `x` back to 0.  The `%` operator will work for this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    text = document.getElementById("text");

var y = 0;

document.getElementById("convert").addEventListener("click", function(){
    context.beginPath();

    for(var i = 0; i < text.value.length; i++){
        if(i > 0 && i % 50 == 0) y++; // Here I try to jump to the next line
        console.log(y)
        x = (i % 50) * 10
        context.rect(x, y * 10, 10, 10);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.stroke();
});
```

JS FIddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/Lx0vq3st/

Hope that helps!